# Laravel 5.2 Auth::check() on exception pages (layouts)

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5

When I abort(404) Laravel 5.2 returns an error page. But when I call Auth::check() of Auth::user() through the dump() method it return null.

But I want a custom error page with the current logged-in user on the screen (for example in the layouts/app.blade.php I want in the menu: Goodmorning *username*).

I tried to enable the web middleware on the app/exceptions/handler.php but that didn't work.

Anny suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could [add custom error message](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#http-exceptions):

```
abort(404, 'ow noo, error 404'.Auth::user()->id);
```

And in the error page:

```
{{ $exception->getMessage() }}
```

Comment: Yes, but I want the normal site, but than in the menu: (Goodmorning *username*). This works, but not with the default layout/app.blade.php

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'normal' site, but you could use custom error pages: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#http-exceptions and also you could work with them like with usual views using `return view('errors.404')->with('Error message');`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin i also have the same problem and it seems like Laravel doesn't see authenticated user on 404 error page...i just tried to dd(Auth::user()) and it gives null....how to solve this? this was my question....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42418507/laravel-cant-see-if-a-user-is-logged-in-on-404-error-page